Angular Firebase functions crash with SSR in Angular 18
When I add import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/compat/functions'; to a component, the second that component loads, the entire frontend crashes fatally with the following error. I remove that import and everything goes back to working smoothly.
[vite] Error when evaluating SSR module [...] .angular/cache/18.1.3/vite/deps_ssr/@angular_fire_compat_functions.js
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at node_modules/@firebase/functions/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/file.js

I've seen solutions removing SSR, but I don't want to do that, and according to this page, @angular/fire is compatible with SSR rendering.
In angular.json I have
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            ...
            "polyfills": ["@angular/localize/init", "zone.js"],
            ...
            "scripts": [],
            "server": "src/main.server.ts",
            "prerender": true,
            "ssr": {
              "entry": "server.ts"
            }

In package.json, I have
"@angular/ssr": "^18.1.3",
"@angular/fire": "^18.0.1",

I'm using Angular 18.1.2 and Node.js v20.11.0. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

please share the github repo with the issue replicated

Can you try running the command firebase deploy --only "functions:ssr" --debug flag and check the logs.

Also seems you are using Node.js v20.11.0. Can you try to update to the latest version Node.js v22.6.0. Also as suggested in this Stackoverflow Link Can you try Adding the angular.json the Node Version of 22, with the line "functionsNodeVersion": 22.

@SandeepVokkareni firebase deploy --only "functions:ssr" --debug returns No targets in firebase.json match '--only functions:ssr'. @NarenMurali I also noticed on each build now I get a new warning: Module 'undici' used by 'node_modules/@firebase/functions/dist/esm-node/index.node.esm.js' is not ESM The warning disappears if I remove Angular Firebase functions.

As @SandeepVokkareni suggested, upgrading node to the latest version (v22.6.0) did solve this issue for me, but only after removing the node-modules folder, the package-lock.json file, and reinstalling all packages with npm i --legacy-peer-deps --save. I wonder if deleting the folder and reinstalling the packages without the node version upgrade would have done the trick.
